# Creating a blurred border in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, gradient

I'm trying to recreate this shape(s) in illustrator and am not sure how it was done. I came up with a similar effect using the blend tool and it works fine for the project I'm working on but am really curious to know how this was done.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- Create a round cornered rectangle (white in this case).
- Go to `Effect > Blur > Gaussian Blur...` and apply some blur (you can also do this via `fx` in the appearance palette).
- Reduce the opacity of the blurred rectangle (you can do this in the appearance panel or the transparency panel).

The exact parameters and values will require some experimentation.

Comment: Of course! Thats perfect. Thanks for the reply :)